# How to set margin to panels without doubling them in the middle?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to have 4 panels (sections).

- The 2 top ones should be along the whole width.
- The 2 others should be next to each other.
- The top one should have no margins at all.
- The 2nd panel should have no top-margin (and no bottom-margin to
  avoid a double one with the ones below).

The problem here is: The 2 panels next to each other have a double margin in the middle. In this case it's 10 + 10. I need them to be 5 both in order to get a total of 10px. However, when I apply this to my code then the extra space left over would end up on the right..

Can anyone help with a solution? Rewriting any code to improve (making it easier to maintain) is also welcome :).

**EDIT:**

I had my container width to 240px for testing the flex i made. This caused the extra space on the right when applying the margin of 5. However, there should be a way to avoid this double margin with any container width. Does anyone have a solution?

**EDIT:**
Had to set the flex-grow to true. Now the margin of 5 + the grow possibility seems to fix the problem. No matter what container size I have.

```css
body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #444444;
  width: 270px;
}

#container > * {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #228822;
  flex-basis: auto;
} 

#container .neighbour {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#container .solo {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

#container .solo.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#container .solo.small {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

#container .solo.no-top {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#container .left {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#container .right {
    margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="solo red small"></section>
  <section class="solo no-top"></section>
  <section class="neighbour left"></section>
  <section class="neighbour right"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: I still had the container width to 240px .. oops, edited it now.. now it works, except: I think there should be a better way than identifying all those panels and applying style to each one of them. There should be a simpler way ! right?

Comment: Actually, Mathijs, you want a generic setup (don't we all?), but you already have 4 exceptions to a generic rule. So, yes, you will have to define all exceptions in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
.no-right{
   margin-right:5px;
}

.no-left{
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

Does tagging that to the end of your stylesheet work?

Comment: It does fix the double margin in the middle, but then the panel is jsut shifted to the left. Leaving extra space on the right. I got it fixed tho, had my container width to 240px (for testing the flex I wrote) but now I think my way of identifying the panels is too complicated.

Comment: This will only work, when the width will be increased to 105px for `#container > *`